# How to send email with an image

Tags: vb.net, email, attachment

I'm trying to send an email with an embedded image and I found this and tried but I'm getting an error of email sending failed.

```
 Try
        Dim strMsg As String = Nothing

        Dim img1 As LinkedResource = New LinkedResource("C:\Users\myname\Desktop\Login.jpg", MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg)
        Dim img2 As LinkedResource = New LinkedResource("C:\Users\myname\Desktop\Login.jpg", MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg)

        img1.ContentId = "Image1"
        img2.ContentId = "Image2"

        Dim mail As New MailMessage()
        mail.From = New MailAddress("myemail.com", "password")
        'mail.CC.Add("ex@test.com.au")
        mail.Bcc.Add("jhaymalagasang@gmail.com")
        mail.Subject = "Reports"

        mail.Priority = MailPriority.High

        strMsg = ""
        strMsg = strMsg & "<html><body><p></p>"
        strMsg = strMsg & "<table width='70%' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' bgcolor='white'>"
        strMsg = strMsg & "<tr>"
        strMsg = strMsg & "<td><h2><center><span style='color:#1C8DFF'>Example Report</span></center></h2></td>"
        strMsg = strMsg & "</tr>"
        strMsg = strMsg & "<tr>"
        strMsg = strMsg & "<td>&nbsp;</td>"
        strMsg = strMsg & "</tr>"
        strMsg = strMsg & "<tr>"
        strMsg = strMsg & "<td><img src=cid:Image1 alt='image description'></td>"
        strMsg = strMsg & "</tr>"
        strMsg = strMsg & "<tr>"
        strMsg = strMsg & "<td><img src=cid:Image2 alt='image description'></td>"
        strMsg = strMsg & "</tr>"
        strMsg = strMsg & "</table></body></html>"



Dim av1 As AlternateView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(strMsg, Nothing, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html)
        av1.LinkedResources.Add(img1)
        av1.LinkedResources.Add(img2)
```

mail.AlternateViews.Add(av1)
            mail.IsBodyHtml = True

```
        Dim smtp As SmtpClient = New SmtpClient()
        smtp.Host = "1.1.1.1" ' Whatever is your smtp server
        smtp.Port = "25"
        smtp.Send(mail)
        MsgBox("Email Sent !", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Success")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error in Email" & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Email Failed")
    End Try
```

Can anyone help me about this?

Comment: You say "attached".  Does that mean that you want to add an attachment or to include it in the HTML?  Either way, show us the code you think you need to use and tell us EXACTLY what happens when you use it, i.e. if you get an error then give us the error message.

Comment: Okay sir. I'll revised my question after.

Comment: I tried another codes sir.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim strMsg As String = Nothing
    Dim img1 As LinkedResource = Nothing

    Try
        img1 = New LinkedResource("C:\For Guidance System\header.jpg", MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg)
        img1.ContentId = "Image1"
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error: " + ex.Message + "", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Loading logo failed!")
        Return IDnums = "" And emailAdd = ""
        Exit Function
    End Try

    Dim mail As New MailMessage()
    mail.From = New MailAddress("myemail@gmail.com", "Description")
    mail.Bcc.Add(CType(emailAdd.ToString, String))
    mail.Subject = "Requested passcode"
    mail.Priority = MailPriority.High
    strMsg = ""
    strMsg = strMsg & "<html><body><p></p>"
    strMsg = strMsg & "<table width='70%' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' bgcolor='white'>"
    strMsg = strMsg & "<tr>"
    strMsg = strMsg & "<td><h2><center><span style='color:#1C8DFF'>Header</span></center></h2></td>"
    strMsg = strMsg & "</tr>"
    strMsg = strMsg & "<tr>"
    strMsg = strMsg & "<td>&nbsp;</td>"
    strMsg = strMsg & "</tr>"
    strMsg = strMsg & "<tr>"
    strMsg = strMsg & "<td><img src=cid:Image1 alt=></td>"
    strMsg = strMsg & "</tr>"
    strMsg = strMsg & "<tr>"
    strMsg = strMsg & "<p>The requested passcode is:    " + final.ToString + "</p>"
    strMsg = strMsg & "<tr>"
    strMsg = strMsg & "<td>&nbsp;</td>"
    strMsg = strMsg & "</tr>"
    strMsg = strMsg & "<tr>"
    strMsg = strMsg & "<p>If you can't login, please refer it to the guidance office for further assistance, else you can request again another passcode.</p>"
    strMsg = strMsg & "</tr>"
    strMsg = strMsg & "<tr>"
    strMsg = strMsg & "<p>Please do not reply to this email. Thank you and God bless!</p>"
    strMsg = strMsg & "</tr>"
    strMsg = strMsg & "</table></body></html>"

Dim av1 As AlternateView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(strMsg, Nothing, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html)
    av1.LinkedResources.Add(img1)

    mail.AlternateViews.Add(av1)
    mail.IsBodyHtml = True

Dim smtp As SmtpClient = New SmtpClient()
```

I solved it by just modifying and adding some codes:

```
    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = False
    smtp.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("myemail@gmail.com", "password")
    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
    smtp.Port = 587
    smtp.EnableSsl = True
    smtp.Send(mail)
```